# Prevent Eigen from creating temporaries when using Eigen::Block

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen library and its block operations to compute matrix multiplications between matrix B and C and the result is saved into matrix A. B has **N** rows and **M** cols, C has **M** rows and **P** cols, where P is a number between 1 and **max_cols**. So A will have **N** rows and **P** cols.  I allocate matrix A, B, C in advance, then into an iterative algorithm I need to modify their values and compute the multiplication. I need this last step to be as fast as possible. Since I cannot know **P** in advance, but I know **max_cols**, I allocate **max_cols** cols for both A and C aforehand and then I compute the matrix multiplication considering the number of cols that I need (P) in that iteration using block operation:

`A.block(0,0,N,P).noalias() = B*C.block(0,0,M,P);`

To avoid temporaries creation I use `noalias()` for matrix A. I use also `Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(false)` to check that temporaries are not created.

I see that with N and M equal to 150 the program does not stop due to `EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC` assertion, while with N and M equal to 180 it does.
Someone can explain why? Can you suggest me how to solve the problem or another way to accomplish my task?

Below a simplified code to reproduce the iussue:

```
#define EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC 
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Eigen>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  uint N, M, P, max_cols;

  // Initial allocation
  N = 150;
  M = 150;
  P = 10;
  max_cols = 50;

  Eigen::MatrixXd B = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N, M);
  Eigen::MatrixXd C = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(M, max_cols);
  Eigen::MatrixXd A(N,max_cols);

  // 
  //Here some code that set the values of the first P columns of C that I will consider into the multiplication
  //

  // This code should be executed as fast as possible without temporaries
  Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(false);

  A.block(0,0,N,P).noalias() = B*C.block(0,0,M,P);  // no assertion

  Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(true);
  // until here

  std::cout<<"first multiplication OK"<<std::endl;

  N = 180;
  M = 180;

  Eigen::MatrixXd B2 = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N, M);
  Eigen::MatrixXd C2 = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(M, max_cols);
  Eigen::MatrixXd A2(N,max_cols);

  // 
  //Here some code that set the values of the first P columns of C that I will consider into the multiplication
  //

  // This code should be executed as fast as possible without temporaries
  Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(false);

  A2.block(0,0,N,P).noalias() = B2*C2.block(0,0,M,P);  // assertion

  Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(true);
  // until here

  std::cout<<"second multiplication OK"<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen, like all optimizing BLAS libraries, uses a [blocking algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Matrix_multiplication_algorithm&oldid=1142721758#Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) for large matrix multiplications. I didn't dive too deep into the implementation but the block size seems to be mostly a function of the level 3 cache size.

Above a [certain limit](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) (default 128 kiB), these blocks are no longer allocated on the stack. You can raise the limit by compiling with `-DEIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT=$((256*1024))` or whatever limit you see fit. But beware that threads other than the main thread may have somewhat limited stack space.

In any case, I wouldn't bother. I just did a benchmark and found no measurable difference in performance. This style of dynamic allocation is cheap compared to the computation itself.

BTW: You can write your block expression better as `A2.topLeftCorner(N,P)`