# Dynamic Eigen's Memory allocation using Eigen tensors

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor, eigen3

I am trying to avoid the creation of temporaries when using Eigen since it's significantly slowing down my code and using up a lot of memory. I was able to set a break point in `check_that_malloc_is_allowed() in Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h` that's triggered when a temporary is created.

Example code:

```
static const int nx = 4;  
static const int ny = 4; 
static const int nz = 4;

Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Product(nx,ny,nz);  
Product.setZero();
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Tensor1(nx,ny,nz);  
Tensor1.setZero();
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Tensor2(nx,ny,nz); 
Tensor2.setZero();

Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(false); //set break point
TensorProduct(Tensor1, Tensor2, Product);
Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(true); //set break point
```

And function that performs tensor product looks like:

```
void TensorProduct(Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& Tensor1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Tensor2, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& Product){
    Product = Tensor1 * Tensor2 * 1i; 

}
```

This triggers the break point and returns the message:

```
 Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:164: void Eigen::internal::check_that_malloc_is_allowed(): Assertion `is_malloc_allowed() && "heap allocation is forbidden (EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC is defined and g_is_malloc_allowed is false)"' failed.
```

I know how to fix this using Eigen matrices but obviously this is not working for a tensor. For an Eigen matrix I would do the following:

```
Product.noalias() = Tensor1 * Tensor2 * 1i;
```

However, this obviously doesn't work for Eigen tensors and I get the error:

```
 error: ‘class Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>’ has no member named ‘noalia
’
  774 |         Product.noalias() = Tensor1 * Tensor2 * 1i;
```

Is there a way to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: is it intended for `Tensor2` to be passed by value (rather than by reference) in `TensorProduct`?

Comment: Yep, fixing the argument solves the issue. At least for me. But note that allocations can also happen within `noalias` products, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76147199/prevent-eigen-from-creating-temporaries-when-using-eigenblock/76147772#76147772 But that is harmless.

Comment: @Pignotto  I was under the impression that passing objects by fixed values and not a reference instead was a bad idea according to the Eigen documentation. Am I missing something? Link: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicPassingByValue.html

Comment: You are misreading the recommendation: You should *not* pass by value. But your function *does* accept the second argument by value. You forgot the `&` for `Tensor2`

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks! I misunderstood your comments, yes indeed ``Tensor2`` is missing the ``&`` in the call. I do however, still get the same error with ``noalias``

Comment: The error: ``‘class Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>’ has no member named ‘noalias’``

Comment: noalias doesn't work. Just use the original code but with the `&` and you should not see any memory allocation